# HTML rendering for brief second before executing IIFE javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very basic authentication function which I am using to redirect users to login.html if they are not signed in. The problem I am having is for a split second, the index.html is rendering before the redirect actually happens. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening with my existing code? I read a post similar to this to create a 'blank page' and redirect based off of that, but is there any other way to avoid this and do it a different way?

app.js

```
const unauthPaths = ['/login.html', '/register.html'];

(function () {

  const currPath = window.location.pathname;
  const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('authToken');

  if (unauthPaths.includes(currPath)) {
    return;
  }

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    window.location.href = '/login.html';
  }

})();
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Home</h1>

<script src="./js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple methods:

- Call [`window.stop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop) as soon as the script can see that a redirect is necessary. Assign to `window.location.href` after calling `window.stop`.
- Move your script to the *top* of the HTML, not the bottom, so that it runs immediately, and not after other parts of the document have been loaded.
- (If you don't like the other methods:) render the rest of the page with JavaScript rather than putting it in the source HTML
- The general approach of doing this on the frontend isn't so elegant, though. Better to move this logic to the *server* instead, sending the authtoken through a cookie, and have the server perform the redirect if needed.